# Custom Regular Expression that will replace a segment of a string based on number and value

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to do is to come up with a custom Javascript function, that when a user calls to a string, will replace a segment of a string based on a number and a value

The number tells the function which segment value should be replaced after the Nth hyphen.

The value tells the function what the new string value replacement will be.

For example:

```
var x = '4-D-5200-P41-120-08C2-8131-0000-9'

var str = RepFinCode(x,2,'ABCD")
```

Therefore, after some processing...

```
str = '4-D-ABCD-P41-120-08C2-8131-0000-9'
```

Comment: Split string by -, replace needed item in array, concat string back. No need to use regex there.

Comment: is there a reason you want to do this with pure regex? You could easily do `x = x.split('-'); x[n] = replacementStr; x = x.join('-')` where 2 is the input number and replacementStr is the input string for the function

Comment: "I would like to do is to come up with a custom Javascript function" It sounds more like you would like us to come up with a custom JavaScript function for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
var x = '4-D-5200-P41-120-08C2-8131-0000-9';
var n = 3;
var s = 'ABCD';
var r = new RegExp('(([^-]+-){' + n + '})[^-]+-');

document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = x.replace(r, '$1' + s + '-');
```

```html
<div id='a'></div>
```

As stated in the comments, this is probably not the way to go - it doesn't shorten the code, is not faster, and not more readable.

Comment: Much appreciated! Thank you :):)